# Complex number raised to a complex number equality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers, for which $z = x+iy$ does the formula $(z^a)^b = (z)^{ab}$ hold?

My approach is the use the principal arguements $z^c = e^{cLog(z)}$ but this leaves me stuck, I've also tried just doing some numerical computations to find some sort of pattern but I can seem to find one. My intuition tells me that $z$ will probably end up having some relation with $a$ and $b$ in the end, but just can't quite seem to solve it

Comment: It turns out it's not a question with a simple answer. This is the best answer I was able to find on short notice. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers

Answer (score 0):

The identity depends on whether you are implying the multi-valued sense or the single valued sense. In the multi-valued sense, this is true when a and b are integers, in particular. In the single valued sense, we take the principal branch so that this identity holds...

See

http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Power/16/04/02/01/

Comment: the question isn't asking for which a and b does this hold, it's asking for which z does this identity hold if a and b are complex numbers

Comment: I realize that. I was giving an example of when the identity holds in the multi-valued sense. The way that he asks the question is a little bit more complicated and following the link gives the answer.